# Erro em uma verificação em função

Tags: c, funções

Preciso fazer um código com várias funções específicas. Em uma delas, com uma matriz quadrada, preciso traçar uma linha primária e uma secundária, ambas cortando no meio em diagonal, restando os números superiores a serem analisados. Exemplo: Uma matriz de 3 por 3 cortaria e restaria o [0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7L8w.jpg).

Pra ilustrar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ok, até ai tudo bem. O problema é que após o usuário inserir os valores a função deveria dizer qual o menor número nesse intervalo delimitado pelas diagonais, mas isso não ocorre.

Segue a função com problema, se precisar mando o código inteiro, mas o restante está certinho, acho que não influencia.

```
void menor(int *matriz [][n])
{
int l,c,menorx;
menorx =0;
for (l=1; l<n; l++){
    for (c=l;c<n-l;c++){
        if(matriz[l][c]<menorx)
            menorx = matriz[l][c];
    }
}
printf("O menor valor eh %d",menorx);
}
```

Comment: Confusão apontadores - inteiros; rever declaração da matriz, `cc -Wall`.

Comment: Tente trocar `menorx = 0;` por `menorx = INT_MAX` (adicionando `#include <limits.h>` ao código).

Comment: Realmente não se pode pressupor o tamanho de menorx. Atribua-o a um valor da própria array e depois o compare entre os outros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Espero que seja o que você procura. Os comentários no código tentam explicar o que o programa faz. Qualquer dúvida poste nos comentários da questão e vou tentar explanar melhor.

**Saída:**

```
Matriz normal:
6 2 5 0 
4 3 7 5 
9 1 5 10 
6 11 8 12 

parte superior:
6 2 5 0 
* 3 7 * 
* * * * 
* * * * 

Menor valor: 0
```

**Código:**

```
#include <stdio.h> 

/* Define a matriz como 4x4. Outros tamanhos podem
   ser utilizados. O código pode ser alterado para
   pedir que o usuário preencha o aranjo */
#define N 4

/* Mostra o menor valor da região */
void menor(const int [][N], int);

/* Mostra o arranjo tal qual é */
void imprimir(const int [][N], int);

/* Mostra a região do array a ser analisada */
void imprimirSup(const int [][N], int);

int main(void)
{
    /* Matriz de exemplo (teste outras!) */
    int matriz[N][N] = {{6, 2, 5, 0}, {4, 3, 7, 5}, {9, 1, 5, 10}, {6, 11, 8, 12}}; 
    /* Imprime normalmente */
    imprimir(matriz, N);

    printf("\n");

    /* Imprime região */
    imprimirSup(matriz, N);

    printf("\n");

    /* Mostra o menor valor inteiro da região */
    menor(matriz, N);

    return 0;
}

void menor(const int arr[][N], int tam){

    int i, j;

    /* Inicialmente supõe que o menor valor será 
       será o primeiro elemento do array, pois até 
       arranjos 1x1 possuem esse elemento e você garante
       pegar um elemento válido inicialmente */
    int menor = arr[0][0];

    /* Dá um loop e varre toda matriz, mas somente atribui valores 
       àqueles que estão na mesma região da função imprimirSup */
    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++){

            if(i <= j && (j + i) < N)
                /* Caso o atual seja menor o atribui como menor */
                if(arr[i][j] <= menor)
                    menor = arr[i][j];                      
        }
    }   

    printf("Menor valor: %d\n", menor);     
}

 /* imprime todo o arranjo */
void imprimir(const int arr[][N], int tam){

    int i, j;

    printf("Matriz normal:\n"); 

    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++)
            printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);

        printf("\n"); 
    }       
}

/* Imprime somente a região a ser analisada */
void imprimirSup(const int arr[][N], int tam){

    int i, j;

    printf("parte superior:\n");

    for(i = 0; i < tam; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < tam; j++){

            if(i <= j && (j + i) < N)
                printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);

            else
                printf("* ");       
        }
        printf("\n"); 
    }       
}
```

Lembre-se de quando for trabalhar com arrays sempre tenha em mente que os índices começam por 0 e terminam em Ordem - 1.